# How to make an horizontal ruler with vimscript?

Tags: vim

i'm trying to do a command that fills up the current line with # , then goes to the begining and rewrites with the date and time, then o, this is my attempt:

```
:nnoremap <F6><Home>
set count = 0
normal i
while count <= columns
  normal #

  set count += 1
endwhile
<Home>R =strftime("%c")<CR>
normal o
```

the result of pressing F6 should be somehting like:

Date and time######################################################################

but yeah this is my first attempt at extending vim so please help me understand how to make this allright.

Answer (score 3):

The right-hand side of a mapping is basically the same as if you typed the commands. This allows you to gradually move from repeatedly typing something to recording a macro (`@q`), to finally making a permanent mapping.

Here's a somewhat literal translation of your attempt:

```
:nnoremap <F6> 80I#<Esc>0R<C-r>=strftime("%c")<CR><Esc>o
```

It uses a fixed width of 80. If you want something more dynamic (like the value of `'textwidth'` when it's > 0), you have to move from direct execution to programmatic interpolation via `:execute`, like this:

```
:nnoremap <F6> :execute 'normal' (&textwidth > 0 ? &textwidth : 80) . "I#\<lt>Esc>"<CR>0R<C-r>=strftime("%c")<CR><Esc>o
```

As you can see, this is already way more cryptic, with a mixture of Ex commands and `:normal` mode, quoting, etc.

The final step is a fully configurable and reusable plugin. Only for those, with elaborate error handling and stuff, you'd typically use separate `:function` definitions, which are then just called from your mapping:

```
function! s:InsertSeparator()
    ...
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <F6> :call <SID>InsertSeparator()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` in vimscript.

```
:nnoremap <F6> I<C-r>=substitute(printf("%-80s", strftime("%c")), '\(\s\)\@<=\s', '#', 'g')<CR><Esc>o
```